# why are these slider buttons not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m trying to build a basic slider using `css` and `jquery` in which images slides and clicking next and previous buttons.
problem is that the buttons are not working.

Code is given below...

```js
$(function(){
  //configrations
  var width = 960;
  var animationSpeed = 1000;
  var pause = 2000;
  var currentSlide = 1;

  //slide selectors
  var $slides = $('.slides');
  var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');

  //slide with buttons
  function nextSlide(){
      if (currentSlide == $slide.length) {
        currentSlide=1;
          $slides.css({'margin-left':'0'});
      }
      else{
        currentSlide= currentSlide+1;
        $slides.animate({'margin-left':'-='+width},animationSpeed);
      }
    };
  function prevSlide(){
        if(currentSlide == 1){}
        else{
      currentSlide = currentSlide-1;
      $slides.animate({'margin-left':'+='+width},animationSpeed);
  };

$('#prev').on('click',prevSlide);
$('#next').on('click',nextSlide);
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0px auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color:#999;
  background-image: url('i/body_black.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'josefin',arial,sans-serif;
}

.container{
  margin:0px auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.slides{
  width: 6000px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide{
  float: left;
}
.slide img{
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
}
.button_container{
  margin: 0px auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 128px;
  left: 0px;
}
.button_container button{
  width: 60px;
  height: 520px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.button_container button:hover{

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.button_container #prev{
  float: left;
}
.button_container #next{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="#slide_container">

  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.falconflooringct.com/product_images/5840f9c136393.jpg" alt="1"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d9/3c/72/d93c729fa88c9e231130f6377a6fded7.jpg" alt="2"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.falconflooringct.com/product_images/5840f9c136393.jpg" alt="3"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d9/3c/72/d93c729fa88c9e231130f6377a6fded7.jpg" alt="4"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.falconflooringct.com/product_images/5840f9c136393.jpg" alt="5"></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="http://www.falconflooringct.com/product_images/5840f9c136393.jpg" alt="1"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
 <div class="button_container">
  <button type="button" name="button" id="prev"><</button>
  <button type="button" name="button" id="next">></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: css may help since you've tagged the CSS

Comment: update animate function with following code: 
`$slides.animate({'margin-left':'+='+width*currentSlide},animationSpeed);`

Comment: show me where you add this live demo any where?

Comment: @arsh_kalsi sorry, its local only till now

Comment: show add it somewhere like jsfiddle or run snippet

Comment: @SuperUser thanks for your answer, but its still the same..something else is wrong with this.

Comment: @arsh_kalsi https://jsfiddle.net/dhavalnagar/quh4b04w/2/ ..link for same..hope it helps

Comment: I think you're missing a closing bracket } on prevSlide(). and on your fiddle you didn't add an external jquery file.

Comment: @joe ohh such a silly mistake....sorry for trouble caused...problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your next and previous button event binding to this one.

```
$('#prev').on("click", function(){
        prevSlide();
    });
$('#next').on("click", function(){
        nextSlide();
    });
```

Working code is below.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  //configrations
  var width = 960;
  var animationSpeed = 1000;
  var pause = 2000;
  var currentSlide = 1;

  //slide selectors
  var $slides = $('.slides');
  var $slide = $slides.find('.slide');

  //slide with buttons
  function nextSlide(){

      if (currentSlide == $slide.length) {

        currentSlide=1;
          $slides.css({'margin-left':'0'});
      }
      else{
        $slides.animate({'margin-left':'-='+width},animationSpeed);
      }
    };

  function prevSlide(){
        alert();
        if(currentSlide == 1){}
        else{
      currentSlide = currentSlide-1;
      $slides.animate({'margin-left':'+='+width},animationSpeed);
      };
  };

$('#prev').on("click", function(){
        prevSlide();
    });
$('#next').on("click", function(){
        nextSlide();
    });

});
```